# Folder Path Selected for Copy Data via UI still EACCES (Permission denied)

Tags: java, android, android-permissions, android-external-storage

I referred https://github.com/afollestad/material-dialogs and it has code to select folder and get its path via application. Following it I implemented below code:

Important I m getting this error on Asus Zenphone 5 running on KitKat API 19.

```
package jss.folderselector;

import android.Manifest;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.afollestad.materialdialogs.folderselector.FolderChooserDialog;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements FolderChooserDialog.FolderCallback {
    TextView path;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button foldersel, copy;


        foldersel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.folder);
        copy = (Button) findViewById(R.id.copy);
        path = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.path);

        foldersel.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                showFolderChooser();
            }
        });

        copy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                moveFile("/sdcard/Download/a.apk",path.getText().toString()+"/a.apk");
            }
        });

    }

    public void showFolderChooser() {

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) !=
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, 1);
            return;
        }
        new FolderChooserDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                .chooseButton(R.string.md_choose_label)
                .allowNewFolder(true, 0)
                // changes label of the choose button
                .initialPath("/sdcard/Download")  // changes initial path, defaults to external storage directory
                .tag("optional-identifier")
                .goUpLabel("Up") // custom go up label, default label is "..."
                .show();
    }

    @Override
    public void onFolderSelection(@NonNull com.afollestad.materialdialogs.folderselector.FolderChooserDialog dialog, @NonNull File folder) {
        Toast.makeText(this, folder.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        path.setText(folder.getAbsolutePath());
        final String tag = dialog.getTag(); // gets tag set from Builder, if you use multiple dialogs
    }

    @Override
    public void onFolderChooserDismissed(@NonNull FolderChooserDialog dialog) {

    }

    public void moveFile(String s, String d) {
        InputStream inStream = null;
        OutputStream outStream = null;

        try {

            File afile = new File(s);
            File bfile = new File(d);

            inStream = new FileInputStream(afile);
            outStream = new FileOutputStream(bfile);

            byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];

            int length;
            //copy the file content in bytes
            while ((length = inStream.read(buffer)) > 0) {

                outStream.write(buffer, 0, length);

            }

            inStream.close();
            outStream.close();

            //delete the original file
            afile.delete();

            System.out.println("File is copied successful!");
            //run();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }


    }
}
```

I could able to pick path for MicroSD card and set that as destination for copying file. But it failed with [image: Permission Denied Error]

I have permission in Manifest for Write External Storage. What else need to be fixed. Since I read that if app choose any folder via UI, app got permission to write, but not working for me.

Manifest file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="jss.folderselector">
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Error Log:

```
02-11 13:54:31.191 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Changed directory to /storage/emulated
02-11 13:54:31.481 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Changed directory to /storage
02-11 13:54:32.101 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Selected index: 0
02-11 13:54:32.111 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Changed directory to /storage/MicroSD
02-11 13:54:33.091 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Selected index: 6
02-11 13:54:33.101 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Changed directory to /storage/MicroSD/WhatsAppold
02-11 13:54:33.581 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Returning /storage/MicroSD/WhatsAppold as result
02-11 13:54:33.581 28199-28255/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: FileObserver received event 32768
02-11 13:54:33.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample D/DirectoryChooserFragment: Changed directory to /storage/MicroSD/WhatsAppold
02-11 13:54:33.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample I/DirChooserSample: Return from DirChooser with result 1
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/MicroSD/WhatsAppold/a.apk: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:88)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(FileOutputStream.java:73)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample.DirChooserSample.moveFile(DirChooserSample.java:109)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample.DirChooserSample$3.onClick(DirChooserSample.java:76)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4478)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18698)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:149)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:609)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err: Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:393)
02-11 13:54:35.601 28199-28199/net.rdrei.android.dirchooser.sample W/System.err:    ... 15 more
```

Image for path on mobile [image: Mobile SDCARD Path]

Comment: please add your permision or menifest file

Comment: `have permission in Manifest for Write External Storage`. That will not do for Marshmellow and above.

Comment: `I could able to pick path for MicroSD card`. The path mentioned in your stacktrace does not exist. Not on a single Android device. (Or otherwise tell which device).  You made it impossible for me to copy that path!

Comment: `Toast.makeText(this, folder.getAbsolutePath(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`. Well what does it show?

Comment: `} catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }`. Of course you should put a Log() statement there too! And display a Toast() to the user to inform about the IOException.

Comment: `Since I read that if app choose any folder via UI, app got permission to write,`. That cannot be true. Permission to read is not permission to write.

Comment: `initialPath("/sdcard/Download") `. You better remove that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
I could able to pick path for MicroSD card. 

/Removable/MicroSD/.......
```

The path in your stacktrace does not exist. Not on a single Android device. (Or otherwise tell which device). (You made it impossible for me to copy that path as you posted an image!)

On modern Android systems you will not be able to write to an SD card. Except for directories private to your app.

Comment: ref attached image for path from mobile Asus Zenfone5

Comment: Why are you not saying that indeed `/MicroSD/WhatsAppold`, like you posted first, does not exist but that it should be `/storage/MicroSD/WhatsAppold/a.apk` instead ? Which indead looks like a path that can exist. If you realize that then you should realize also that the screendump with `> root > Removable > MicroSD > WhatsAppold` is a non existing not usable path which does not tell the real path like `/storage/MicroSD/WhatsAppold`. You better use a file manager that tells you the real path

Comment: So what is the solution now, u got real path from file manager, and from error log. Advice now. I m badly stuck here

Comment: You are not reading my answer? `On modern Android systems you will not be able to write to an SD card. Except for directories private to your app.`.

Comment: how WhatsApp allow to create backup on SD card and not in app directories?

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using KitKat which is API 19, You need to implicitly declare the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in the manifest.
As the documentation suggest:

> This permission is enforced starting in API level 19. Before API level 19, this permission is not enforced and all apps still have access to read from external storage. You can test your app with the permission enforced by enabling Protect USB storage under Developer options in the Settings app on a device running Android 4.1 or higher.

But remember if you are targeting API above 19 and if you only add `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` in your manifest it will automatically add the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` during build time, therefore you do not need the extra read permission. But in your case, you need to have it since you are targeting 19 and lower.